# Is it possible to get barcolor which set by another pine script?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I want to create a script based on another one to which source I do not have access.
Is it possible to get barcolor which is set by another pine script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Using this script loaded on your chart, you can go in its inputs and select a source from another indicator loaded on your chart (#1 and #2 in screenshot). The script will color bars on the condition that whatever source you configured is >0, but you could ofc write any condition you want:

```
//@version=4
study("Barcolor", "", true)
i_source = input(close)
barcolor(i_source > 0 ? color.orange : color.purple)
```

If you can load the protected script on your chart, you can see its outputs with the Data Window (#3 and #4 in screenshot), so you'll be able to figure out if there is an output that you will be able to use as an input into your bar coloring script.

[image]